# $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $8n+2$; what can be stated about $n$?

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues, jacobi-symbol

When $a$ exists for which $a^2 \equiv -1 \mod {8n+2}$, then what can be stated about $n$? I am not looking for theoretical statements about the prime factorization of $8n+2$; I need explicit statements about $n$, when possible.
In case that is not possible, then a statement about $8n+2$ is OK.

Comment: You state that you are not looking for theoretical statements about the prime factorization of $8n+2$, but that is where the truth lies.  Are you not looking for the truth? :)  Or are you just looking for some necessary, but perhaps not sufficient conditions, i.e. an incomplete sketch that can nonetheless say something descriptive about $n$?

Comment: I like a more explicit truth - if there is one :-)

Comment: I believe one equivalent phrasing that avoids explicit mention of prime factors is that $8n+2$ can be written as $a^2+b^2$ where $a,b$ are relatively prime integers.

Comment: OK that comes close to an explicit statement about $n$ - why not promote this into an answer?

Comment: One can also deduce that $a,b$ must be odd, hence $n$ can be written as the sum of two triangular numbers.  The relatively prime condition does not really translate nicely to this setting, so I would view this as a necessary but not quite sufficient condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the numbers which have $-1$ as a quadratic residue are characterized precisely as those numbers not divisible by $4$ or by any prime of the form $4k+3$.  Since $8n+2$ does not fall in the former category, it is necessary and sufficient that it be $2$ times the product of primes of type $4k+1$.

This latter property is equivalent to being expressible as the sum of two co-prime odd squares, so $8n + 2 = a^2 + b^2$ for some $(a,b)=1$.

Finally, we get a necessary condition on $n$ by noting that $n = (a^2-1)/8 + (b^2-1)/8$, so $n$ is the sum of two triangular numbers.  This would be sufficient, except there is no direct way to express the coprimality of the underlying values of $a$ and $b$.  The best we could say is that "$n$ is the sum of two triangular numbers $A,B$ such that $8A+1$ and $8B+1$ have no common factor".